# Is there a way to install OpenCV + VIZ using MacPorts on Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, macports

I am trying to use `VIZ` software of `OpenCV`, but looks like this package is not installed (can't find `viz.hpp`). Is there a way to install it using `MacPorts`? I have `VTK` installed already.